# Updating environment variables

Tags: 16.04, environment-variables, bashrc

I had to erase a previous Ubuntu version on my pc, and reinstall a new version (16.04 LTS) to work. After that, I installed the source code of several programs that I work with in the previous version. In the instructions of this software, there is a step to upgrade the environment variables:

```
SSU-ALIGN has been successfully built
=====================================
The final step is to update your environment variables:
If you are using the bash shell, add the following three:
lines to the ’.bashrc’ file in your home directory:

    export PATH="\$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
    export MANPATH="\$MANPATH:/usr/local/share/man"
    export SSUALIGNDIR="/usr/local/share/ssu-align-0.1.1"

And then source that file to update your current environment with the command:

    source ~/.bashrc
```

When I add the previous three lines at the end of my .bashrc file, the program works, but others commands like `ls` or `cd` can't be used.

I have read other similar posts, but I can not solve the problem. I JUST CAN'T REMEMBER HOW TO UPDATE MY ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES OR WHERE TO PUT THE THREE LINES.

I installed this software in the next path: ~/Desktop/SOFTWARE/ssu-align-0.1.1

Comment: Don't escape `$`, i.e. just `"$PATH:/usr/...` and `"$MANPATH:/usr/local/...`

Comment: I have deleted the "/" before $ in PATH and MANPATH and everything is working perfect. Thank you very much Gunnar Hjalmarsson

Comment: Source of the instructions seems to be page 10 of http://eddylab.org/software/ssu-align/Userguide.pdf

Comment: Adding `/usr/local/path` is probably unnecessary as it should already be there. Use `echo $PATH` to display current path. If directory appears twice then remove the line in your `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the `~/.bashrc` file!

Open with e.g. `nano`

```
/bin/nano ~/.bashrc
```

and go to the last lines.

You have to delete the backslash `\` before `$PATH` and `$MANPATH`, as Gunnar said in his comment. The correct lines have to be read as

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export MANPATH="$MANPATH:/usr/local/share/man"
export SSUALIGNDIR="/usr/local/share/ssu-align-0.1.1"
```

Save the file, and source the bashrc with

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I have solved the problem both answers, than you

Comment: Note that sourcing ~/.bashrc won't restore the correct PATH and MANPATH. OP would have to close the shell and open a new one. Also since the PATH is wrong, OP might need to call `/usr/bin/nano` instead of just `nano`.